# typeof(x) as a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, auto

I have a variable `x`, declared as:

```
auto x = f(y);
```

where `f` is a function and `y` a variable, both defined somewhere else. Now I would like to declare a `std::vector` holding elements of the type of `x`, so I write:

```
std::vector<typeof(x)> v;
```

This results in a compiler error. A solution is to put here the explicit argument of `x`, but I think this defeats the purpose of `auto` in `x`'s declaration! So how can I use the type of `x` as a template argument, without explicitly writing the type (so that in the type changes, my code remains valid).

Comment: Use `decltype()` instead

Comment: Did you mean [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)? Or are you indeed using GCC and its [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html)? Also, can you post the complete compiler error message?

Comment: @DimChtz `decltype` works. Thanks.

Comment: @Cornstalks I did not know `typeof` was GCC specific.

Comment: @becko yes it is, but `decltype` is a c++ 11 feature

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only GNU Compiler has the `typeof`. Instead, use the `decltype` which is a c++ 11 feature.